# Yii2 password validation regular expression

Tags: regex, validation, yii2, passwords

This is the part of the original code for password hash validation of Yii2.

```
if (!preg_match('/^\$2[axy]\$(\d\d)\$[\.\/0-9A-Za-z]{22}/', $hash, $matches)
         || $matches[1] < 4
         || $matches[1] > 30
     ) {
         throw new InvalidArgumentException('Hash is invalid.');
}
```

e.g. password: 12345678
password hash: $2y$13$JLD4tOba6KmwkXZFeRB9FufjVTQlmjmQkjwRzAR59/Rp1RK4bF7dO

For my project as per client requirement I am hashing password by sha256.
e.g. password: 12345678
password hash: ef797c8118f02dfb649607dd5d3f8c7623048c9c063d532cc95c5ed7a898a64f
Can anyone provide me the regular expression code for hash validation?

Comment: `~^\$2[axy]\$(\d\d)\$[./\dA-Za-z]{22,}$~` should work fine for you. Please clarify what's not working

Comment: Thank you. What about the variable $matches?

Comment: That will be populated using capture grup so for the sample provided $matches[1]` will be equal to `13`

Answer (score 0):

`SHA256` hash is 256 bit long. If you write it as hexadecimal string you can use 1 char to represent 4 bits, so the result will be 64char long string and the regular expression can be like this:

```
/[a-fA-F0-9]{64}/
```

There are no characters with special meaning in `SHA256` hash.

Btw. `SHA256` algorithm **was not designed for encrypting/hashing passwords** so it's not a good idea to use it that way. The main issue is that counting the hash with this algorithm is cheap, which means the brute force or dictionary attacks goes through possible passwords pretty quickly. You should consider explaining that to your client and trying to persuade him to use algorithm designed for password hashing if possible.

Comment: It is a requirement for them. Cannot change it. When a user login, we will be prepending a random salt to the passwordhash and hash it again. Everytime the same user login, a different salt will be prepend to his passwordhash which will be compare to the password hash, which will be again hash with the random salt, stored in database.

Comment: That's not enough. If the DB gets leaked someone might use the salts and hashes stored there to try dictionary/brute force attack to get the passwords. Than they can try to use the email/password combination elsewhere. Not everyone listens to security recommendations and uses different password for each site. But I do understand that you might not be able to change it when it's client's requirement.